Can we search large lists using calculated columns, even that we cannot add calculated columns as index inside lists?
Inside SharePoint online we cannot index calculated columns at the list level, so we cannot filter large lists based on the calculated columns inside list views. but what about Search? can we search large lists using calculated columns and sort the search results based on the calculated columns? In other words, is there a relation between index at list level and the ability to search calculated columns?
As I have large lists which might contain 100,000 items in the future for each, and i am using PnP Modern search web part to show data from those lists. i want to be able to filter the PnP Search result using the calculated column, so is this achievable? or since we cannot add calculated columns inside list indexes then this mean that we will not be able to filter and sort Search Results using this calculated column? or this is not the case?
Thanks

SharePoint online does not allow indexing of calculated columns at the list level, so it is not possible to filter large lists based on calculated columns inside list views. However, it is possible to search large lists using calculated columns and sort the search results based on the calculated columns. There is no direct relation between list-level indexing and the ability to search calculated columns. In the scenario described, it should be possible to filter the PnP Search result using the calculated column.

ok thanks understood
